# Save data in a local database using Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dao

According to google instructions in [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room](https://stackoverflow.com) I have added the following code to define a DAO in onCreate fun:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun getAll(): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<User>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
           "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): User

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: User)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: User)
}
```

but I have ***'UserDao' is an interface so it cannot be local.*** Error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed it from the onCreate function body, it was fixed.